# How to use the same Component view at multiple URLs in Ionic 2’s DeepLinker?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, deep-linking

I’m trying to achieve the following configuration in my Ionic (3.9.2) app using the Ionic 2 DeepLinker, where I have regular versions of my pages at index.html, /terms, and /card, and differently styled versions at /club/index.html, /club/terms and /club/card:

`@NgModule({ 
  declarations: MyComponents, 
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule, 
    // DeepLinker!!
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { locationStrategy : 'path' }, { 

    links : [ 

      { component : HomePage, name : 'Home', segment : '' }, 

      { component : TermsPage, name : 'Terms of Use', segment : 'terms' }, 

      { component : CardPage, name : 'Savings Card', segment : 'card' },
     // Club Aliases; these pages will have the same content as above, 
     // but slightly different styles, defined elsewhere.
       { component : HomePage, name : 'Home', segment : 'club' } 

       { component : TermsPage, name : 'Terms of Use', segment : 'club/terms' }, 

       { component : CardPage, name : 'Savings Card', segment : 'club/card' },
    //...`

Is there a way to achieve this using the Ionic 2 [DeepLinker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.0/api/navigation/DeepLinker)?

Some notes:

We navigate to pages by following links (and preventing default):

```
<a href="/terms" (click)="openPage('TermsPage', $event)">Terms of Use</a>
```

where `openPage` pushes a page onto the nav stack using NavController's [Nav Component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/), like so:

```
$event.preventDefault();
this.nav.push(page.component, params);
```

We also had to setup our webserver to rewrite subdirectories (e.g. “/terms”) to index.html.  Info: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10565#issuecomment-282659179

And I also forked @ionic-app-scripts to get this (rewrite to index.html) working on my local development (e.g. live reload) server:
    https://github.com/senseijames/ionic-app-scripts

Answer (score 1):

In the DeepLinkConfig links 'name' is simply a string identifier which can be used to resolve the page component by its string alias. I would recommend omitting whitespaces and capitalization and adjusting your implementation like so:

**Refactor DeepLinkConfig**

```
   links : [
      { component : HomePage, name : 'home', segment : '' },
      { component : TermsPage, name : 'terms', segment : 'terms' },
      { component : CardPage, name : 'card', segment : 'card' },
      { component : HomePage, name : 'club', segment : 'club' }
      { component : TermsPage, name : 'club-terms', segment : 'club/terms' },
      { component : CardPage, name : 'club-card', segment : 'club/card' }
   ]
```

**Refactor click handler**

```
openPage(name: string, params: any) {
    this.nav.push(name, params);
}
```

**Refactor button markup**

```
<button ion-button (click)="openPage('terms', {})">Terms of Use</button>
<button ion-button (click)="openPage('club-terms', {})">Club Terms</button>
<button ion-button (click)="openPage('club-card', { id: 1234, username: 'someuser', rewards: false })">Savings Card</button>
```

This way you can navigate by name and not have to import page components into each controller in order to link to the page component itself. Also ion-button attribute decorated button elements are the preferred navigation UI per IonicFramework documentation and using them would avoid the need to prevent the default behavior of vanilla html anchors.